# Representing Spherocylinder (capsule) in Paraview

Tags: vtk, quaternions, paraview

I am trying to render spherocylinders (Capsules, pills, E.coli) in Paraview. I am trying to understand how the author [https://discourse.paraview.org/t/tensor-glyph-and-other-quadrics-than-ellipsoids/397/2] got such a nice render.

The VTK legacy allows to write symmetric 3x3 tensors (3 components). The renderer I am using now is Ovito, where I need to import 4 components of a quaternion... Ovito works fine, but I want to try Paraview due to its ray-tracing features...

Any advice is very well received...